# Android 6 Update Changed SD Card Name

Tags: external-sd, 6.0-marshmallow, motorola-moto-g3

I have a Motorola Moto G3 Smartphone and I installed the Android 6 update yesterday. After installing the update, I found out that all my playlists, App preferences and basically everything that relied on the external Sandisk 16 GB micro SD card is Messed up or damaged. I found out the cause of this is that the base name for the SD card has been changed from 'sdcard1' to '3835-3237'. I am unable to change the SD card name in Mobile (using ES file explorer) or externally via PC (no matter what I change it to, it still shows those numbers on my mobile). I have a heavily customized my phone and I would prefer not to root it just to change the SD card name. Could anyone please tell me a method to change the SD Card name without having to root the phone? Or any way I can do it externally?

Answer (score 1):

Android 6.0 now uses the volume serial number of the formatted partition as a *unique* identifier to distinguish which SD card you might be using.

I guess this could be useful in case you have a device that could theoretically support multiple SD cards.

Comment: Is this based on opinion? If not, can you provide us  means to independently verify your claim in first paragraph?

Comment: Here's a screenshot on my device, showing how my SD card is called in /storage (*77EB-1515* in my case)  

([Solid Explorer](http://i.imgur.com/IicQNlA.png))

If I run the command *blkid* (root needed) to see all the attributes of all block devices, you can see the SD card has that UUID  


([Console](http://i.imgur.com/bH2AAqb.png))

You could do the same in Windows or any other operating systems using OS-specific commands.

Comment: And it could also be extremely counter-productive: imagine your heavily-customized phone references /storage/1234-5678 in lots and lots of apps,  and then you buy a faster SD card. Now what? Reconfigure _everything_?

Comment: You could change the volume UUID to match the previous card if you don't want to relink everything to the new volume.